# Nonexistent LiteralPath Property of System.IO.FileInfo Object Bound to Parameter

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to understand parameter binding in PowerShell, specifically, why a command like

```bsh
Get-ChildItem users.csv | Get-Acl
```

works.

`Get-Acl` accepts 2 parameters through the pipeline:

- `-Path`

  - of type String[]
  - accepts parameters both ByValue and ByPropertyName
- `-LiteralPath`

  - of type String[]
  - accepts parameters both ByValue and ByPropertyName

The output of

```bsh
Get-ChildItem users.csv
```

is a `System.IO.FileInfo` object which PowerShell should not be able to bind to the parameters of `Get-Acl`.

This is because:

1. Binding by value fails as PowerShell will not cast the FileInfo object to a string.
2. Binding by property name should fail as well because the FileInfo object does not have any `Path` or `LiteralPath` properties.

Running a trace shows that the `LiteralPath` parameter of `Get-Acl` is successfully bound by PropertyName:

```bsh
Trace-Command -Expression {
    Get-ChildItem users.csv | Get-Acl
} -Name ParameterBinding -PSHost
```

The output is as follows (excerpt shown):

```
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [LiteralPath] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName NO COERCION
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\xxx\users.csv] to parameter [LiteralPath]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Binding collection parameter LiteralPath: argument type [String], parameter type [System.String[]], collection type Array, element type [System.String], no coerceElementType
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Creating array with element type [System.String] and 1 elements
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Argument type String is not IList, treating this as scalar
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Adding scalar element of type String to array position 0
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         Executing VALIDATION metadata: [System.Management.Automation.ValidateNotNullOrEmptyAttribute]
ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [System.String[]] to param [LiteralPath] SUCCESSFUL
```

Where does PowerShell get the `LiteralPath` property of the FileInfo object from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `LiteralPath` has an alias: `PSPath` - and the `FileInfo` objects returned by the `FileSystem` provider all have `PSPath` attributes!

#### `PSPath` Alias on `LiteralPath`:

```
PS C:\> (Get-Command Get-Acl).Parameters['LiteralPath'].Aliases
PSPath
```

#### Provider properties on FileInfo

```
PS C:\> Get-Item C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe|Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty

   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo

Name          MemberType   Definition
----          ----------   ----------
PSChildName   NoteProperty string PSChildName=notepad.exe
PSDrive       NoteProperty PSDriveInfo PSDrive=C
PSIsContainer NoteProperty bool PSIsContainer=False
PSParentPath  NoteProperty string PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Windows\System32
PSPath        NoteProperty string PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
PSProvider    NoteProperty ProviderInfo PSProvider=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
```

As you can see, the `PSPath` NoteProperty holds the provider-qualified literal path to the file system item, just like in your trace output where you get `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\Users\xxx\users.csv`